# Accessing For in Loop Collection View Swift

Tags: swift

I have this array that I created: `let yourShares = ["90%","40%", "23%","15%","10%"]` Then to acess this:

```
 for yourShare in yourShares {
        dataSource[0].yourShareTitle = "90%"
        dataSource[1].yourShareTitle = "40%"
        dataSource[2].yourShareTitle = "23%"
        dataSource[3].yourShareTitle = "10%"
    }
```

Then to access this I put this code in an extension for collection view

`let yourShare = model.dataSource?[indexPath.row]
        cell.yourShareLabel.text = "Your Share \(yourShare!.yourShareTitle)"
        cell.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1)`

The problem is when I run this it just prints optional. Why, and how could I fix that? ~ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap it

```
if let yourShare = model.dataSource?[indexPath.row]?.yourShareTitle as? String {
        cell.yourShareLabel.text = "Your Share \(yourShare)"
        cell.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1)
}
```

Comment: This does not work: I am getting an error that says value of type 'String' has no member 'yourShareTitle'

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!